# Workaround for bug ConvexHullMesh

Tags: computational-geometry

`ConvexHullMesh[pts]` gives an object that excludes many of the points contained in `pts`. Here is a minimal example:

```
examplePts = {{125532/121135, 52654/111821, 1069901/1261496}, {81508/
    78653, 82423/175041, 561925/662552}, {111652/107741, 141253/
    299976, 1744659/2057072}, {44933/43359, 191656/407013, 691887/
    815776}, {204538/197373, 144143/306111, 89027/104968}, {109988/
    106135, 201670/428277, 1566859/1847408}, {52037/50214, 404989/
    860049, 245861/289880}, {165232/159443, 46737/99251, 501067/
    590768}, {76568/73885, 84344/179109, 454643/536016}, {89677/86535,
     39905/84742, 48377/57037}, {92782/89531, 238051/505518, 382991/
    451544}, {474886/458247, 163720/347673, 1974665/2328136}, {48318/
    46625, 26219/55678, 257943/304114}, {38558/37207, 67187/142677, 
    883575/1041736}, {45690/44089, 161360/342657, 294413/
    347108}, {53513/51638, 58343/123896, 273245/322156}, {177256/
    171045, 104893/222747, 341747/402916}, {13842/13357, 82498/175191,
     926989/1092920}, {96606/93221, 282587/600093, 775411/
    914204}, {52257/50426, 170791/362688, 486633/573740}, {189532/
    182891, 263053/558612, 745367/878784}, {100832/97299, 286324/
    608031, 930125/1096616}, {92272/89039, 70114/148893, 614397/
    724376}, {29312/28285, 82715/175653, 1219337/1437608}, {112480/
    108539, 160606/341061, 32027/37760}, {35591/34344, 99173/210603, 
    48875/57624}, {28741/27734, 10025/21289, 659477/777528}, {83426/
    80503, 33805/71788, 71729/84569}, {86908/83863, 129176/274317, 
    660583/778832}, {18352/17709, 57933/123026, 334607/394504}};
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[examplePts], ConvexHullMesh[examplePts]
 ]
```

In MMA 12.1.1 for Linux this produces the following plot:

[image: ConvexHullMesh]

Note that many points that are in `pts` are not included in the convex hull. I provided the points already as rationalized data to show that the solution for a similar problem encountered in [ConvexHullMesh sometimes excludes valid points from convex hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85466/45020) does not work to solve this problem. (The same problem still occurs when using real numbers.) Also the problem can be even more clear and not an issue of the line not being visible because it is thin in other examples but I wanted to post one with only 30 points.

It seems that bugs like this have been around for many versions of MMA so I don't have too high a hope of this being fixed any time soon. Is there any workaround?

---

If this issue has been solved in version 12.2 my question still stands and I am looking for a workaround in 12.1.

Note that the `ConvexHullMesh` is wrong and not just wrongly depicted in the plot. This can easily be seen from its FullForm that the largest included point is `1.0363015752208307` while there are many points greater than `1.03631`.

Comment: Might help? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223405/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-within-a-concave-3d-polyhedron

Comment: @Kvothe: Your problem may be caused by graphic drivers.

Comment: @user64494, no the actual mesh is wrong as can be seen by looking at its full form. It is not just a plotting issue.

Comment: Does `BoundaryMesh[DelaunayMesh[examplePts]]` work in 12.1?

Answer (score 1):

In 12.2

```
ConvexHullRegion[examplePts]
```

> `Polyhedron[Number of points:30 Number of faces: 34 ]`

```
Region[%]
```

[image]

The result of `Show[ListPointPlot3D[examplePts],  Region[ConvexHullRegion[examplePts]]]` is badly seen.

Addition. The commands

```
ConvexHullRegion[N[examplePts, 15]]
```

and

```
ConvexHullMesh[examplePts]
```

perform a similar result for me:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[examplePts], ConvexHullMesh[examplePts]]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[examplePts],Region[ConvexHullRegion[examplePts]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Okay maybe they just fixed it in 12.2 . Note that I can't fully see the convex hull is indeed correct since you did not include a plot of the points to provide some scale but I assume you checked and that it now works correctly.

Comment: @Kvothe: I use another command `ConvexHullRegion` instead of `ConvexHullMesh`.

Comment: Right but that command was introduced in 12.2.

Comment: @Kvothe: Upgrade your Mathematica.

Comment: Haha, if only life was so simple.